# php-curl-class check if login okay

Tags: php, curl

I use the [php-curl-class](https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class/) 
I like to check that the login data are correct. The download area is protected with htaccess and if the login data correct the download start. If the login data not correct the download don't start, but i get the HttpStatusCode 200! Her my complette code, sorry if my description not enough, but what more should explain?

```
$HttpStatusCode = false;
                $curl->setBasicAuthentication(user, pw);            
                if ($curl->getHttpStatusCode() !== '401') {
                    $tmpfile = $_GET['vers'];
                    $tmppath = $_GET['path'].'/';
                    $curl->download(DOWNLOAD_PATH.$tmppath.$tmpfile, function ($instance, $tmpfile) {                       
                        $save_to_path = FS_UPDATES . basename($instance->url);
                        $fh = fopen($save_to_path, 'wb');
                        stream_copy_to_stream($tmpfile, $fh);
                        fclose($fh);
                    });                 
                    $curl->close;
                } else {
                    $HttpStatusCode = true;
                }
```

I get all the time `HttpStatusCode 200`! The download only start if the login data correct. Thats okay, but how to check the login is wrong? I would very appreciate if anyone can help me, because the examples didn't help me.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `but nothing works.` yet you get `HttpStatusCode 200` - please be  a little more descriptive with what is and is not actually happening and add relevant code not merely links to an external library

Comment: nice answer, thank you!

Comment: Sounds like your HTTP Auth setup/implementation might not be correct to begin with. You should not get a 200 from the server, if the credentials don’t match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks to all for like to help. Now i find by myself the solution. ;-) It's all the time: "99.9% the bug sit in front of the computer" ;-) In this case ME!!! ;-)
So here ist the solution, may be some other people need it! Now i get the "401" Status Code!

```
        $tmpfile = $_GET['vers'];
        $tmppath = $_GET['path'];
        $curl->setBasicAuthentication(user, pw);    
        $curl->get(DOWNLOAD_PATH.$tmppath.'/'.$tmpfile);
        $HttpStatusCode = true;
        if ($curl->getHttpStatusCode() !== '401') { $HttpStatusCode = false;
                $curl->download(DOWNLOAD_PATH.$tmppath.'/'.$tmpfile, function ($instance, $tmpfile) {                       
                    $save_to_path = DIR_UPDATES . basename($instance->url);
                    $fh = fopen($save_to_path, 'wb');
                    stream_copy_to_stream($tmpfile, $fh);
                    fclose($fh);
                });
            }
            $curl->close;
```